# c# error when parse string to JSON

Tags: json, parsing

I have a bit text when i trying to parse it to JSON in c# program through error "**Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 6.**"

text:

```
"data":[{"username":"sex","bio":"#u24e2kyu24d4u24e7pressionsninstagramsex@gmail.com","website":"","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.com/profiles/profile_37086_75sq_1363954517.jpg","full_name":"sex","id":"37086"}]
```

My code:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(text);
```

I want to get username value when parse to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put a `{ }` around the entire string.

I.e. change text to:

```
{"data":[{"username":"sex","bio":"#u24e2kyu24d4u24e7pressionsninstagramsex@gmail.com","website":"","profile_picture":"http://images.ak.com/profiles/profile_37086_75sq_1363954517.jpg","full_name":"sex","id":"37086"}]}
```